# CMSampleBuffer not being displayed by AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer

Tags: swift, avfoundation, h.264

The project I am working on takes an h264-encoded bitstream and displays the video frames.

The decoder––which takes raw bytes and outputs a CMSampleBuffer containing a video frame––is working well. It's formatDescription contains the expected values, it correctly interprets NALU types, all that. I may be wrong though, as this is my first time working with all of this, so if anyone suspects that the problem may be in the decoder I would be happy to provide code.

My problem arises when I pass a CMSampleBuffer to an AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer. The video frames aren't appearing on screen.

This is the function that is supposed to display the video frames:

```
func videoFrameReceived(_ frame: CMSampleBuffer) {
    videoLayer.enqueue(frame)

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        self?.videoLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This is how I initialized my AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer:

```
if let layer = videoLayer {
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 640, height: 480)
    layer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect

    let cmTimebasePointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CMTimebase?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    let status = CMTimebaseCreateWithMasterClock(kCFAllocatorDefault, CMClockGetHostTimeClock(), cmTimebasePointer)
    layer.controlTimebase = cmTimebasePointer.pointee

    if let controlTimeBase = layer.controlTimebase, status == noErr {
        CMTimebaseSetTime(controlTimeBase, kCMTimeZero)
        CMTimebaseSetRate(controlTimeBase, 1.0)
    }

    self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the `status` and `error` properties of the layer ?

Comment: Yep. No problem there; status == ".rendering" and error == "nil"

Comment: Have you checked the timing of the `AVSampleBuffer`s produced by your decoder ? Does it work better if you don't set the layer's `controlTimebase` ?

Comment: Yeah. Still nothing

Comment: Try `VTDecompressionSession` to see if it can decode your frames.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I did finally get it working: [github](https://github.com/philipshen/H264)

Answer (score 1):

User figured out how to do it and posted a link to the solution as a comment to the question. The link was broken,
[here is the updated link to solution](https://github.com/philipshen/H264Decoder/blob/master/H264Decoder.swift)